# Emacs switching out of terminal

Tags: shell, emacs, terminal, buffer

When running terminal mode in Emacs using `M-x term` using `C-x C-o` I cannot switch to another buffer to continue working on things. I know that this is possible with `M-x shell` but with this command there are certain aspects of the shell that do not work (less, more, man pages, etc...). I was wondering if there is a way around this or if when using terminal mode you are confined to the buffer that the terminal is open in until you exit.

Comment: Just a general comment: Why would you use man pages from a shell inside Emacs? Just use `M-x woman`. In the same vain `less`, just open the file with Emacs.

Comment: @pmr mostly for dmesg | less. man pages were kinda rare but its just easier to have that 1 buffer manage it than opening new buffers for each

Comment: mostly for dmesg | less. man pages were kinda rare but its just easier to have that 1 buffer manage it than opening new buffers for each

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In terminal mode you have to use `C-c o` to switch to the other buffer. `C-c` is the "terminal escape character"

http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Terminal-emulator.html

Comment: I remember spending an embarrassing amount of time googling that a while back... glad it helped

Comment: Emacs Tip: If you have questions about how to accomplish something in a particular mode, use `C-h m` to see key bindings and some brief documentation about that mode.

Comment: @Chris I did use it but either a name or its function was not clear to me which is why I asked

Comment: Jesus, good to know. By the way, I just discovered that I misread your question. I thought it was about `shell`, but now I see it's about `term`. `term` doesn't respond to `C-h` in the same way as normal modes. I'm surprised that `term` doesn't display some sort of warning text the first time you run it, to tell you how to get out of it. More surprising to me, though, is that Jesus replied with "I did use [`C-h m`]", since it does nothing for me when running `term`.

Comment: It turns out that `term` doesn't respond to the usual input while the initial command program is still running, since the input goes to the tty to be handled by the command. Once it exits, however, the buffer is just a text file and commands like `C-h` work as expected.

Comment: @ChrisPage I used C-h m to check hotkeys in the other buffer to make sure I wasn't losing my mind.

Comment: I had to use `C-x o` on mine :-)

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption that you are using a Linux distro:

1. `Ctrl + d` to terminate the Terminal Emulator process
2. `C-c k` then `ENTER` to kill the associated buffer