# How to switch from shell buffer to another

Tags: emacs

I learn to use emacs. When I enter M-x shell , I enter the shell mode, but I don't know how to exit shell mode. I want to be back to  fundamental mode to continue to my editing work. I search this question [Emacs switching out of terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451955/emacs-switching-out-of-terminal), but when I press C-c o , the input will be treated as a command, so how to exit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell will be running in a buffer. You can switch back to the buffer where you were doing your work using `C-x b`.

Comment: I have changed the title of the question to reflect what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

You can try shell-toggle.el for quick jump back and forth between your current buffer and a shell buffer.

You can also try my hacked version of shell-toggle, which let you open a shell in the path of your current buffer (file). See the following link:

http://zhangda.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/my-hack-on-shell-toggle/

Comment: My simple but IMHO effective solution has been to bind C-z to `shell` globally, and in `shell-mode-map` to `bury-buffer`.